# Why number of connection increase with gatling

Tags: gatling

I use gatling to perform some load tests.

Here is the code :

```
 setUp(
    fred.inject(
      splitUsers(8000) into(constantUsersPerSec(12) during(30 seconds) randomized) separatedBy(constantUsersPerSec(5) during(15 seconds) randomized)
    )
```

Why the number of connection increase (more than 2000 connections with status ESTABLISHED) ?

Am i doing somthing the wrong way ?

With `ab`, the number of connection remains constant, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Gatling simulates browsers, so each virtual user has its own connection pool. Then, Gatling 2 is supposed to close it once a vu is done.

ab has a shared connection pool (if you enable Keep-Alive of course) and you then set the number of concurrent requests.

You're probably comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation. I don't understand *once a vu is done* ? And why after a virtual user has finished his scenario. the connection remains established ?